# About android architecture?

Tags: android, architecture

Anybody can explain to me about this diagram [image]

How can Android application which run on Dalvik call a native lib from VM?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> > How can Android application which run on Dalvik call a native lib from VM?

They use [JNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface), as explained in the diagram. Well, it actually does not *call native libs from the VM*... it executes native code (C or C++) which resides in a standar Linux library (those ones with the .so extension).